# get data of particular time

Tags: mysql, time

I have a table in which real time feed rate data of a cement mill are stored. The table is updated every one minute. Is it possible to get the data for any time I enter? For example, if I enter the time as 5 a.m. is it possible to get the feed rate datum at 5 a.m.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM tablename 
WHERE date_field BETWEEN '2014-06-18 05:00:00' AND '2014-06-18 05:59:59';
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM tablename 
WHERE date_field = '2014-06-18 05:00:00';
```

**EDIT:**
May be you can try something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename 
WHERE DATE(date_field ) = DATE(NOW()) 
date_field BETWEEN CAST('05:00:00' AS time) AND CAST('05:59:59' AS time);
```

Comment: I have a text box to type the time and another label to display the feed rate for the time typed in text box. And I don't want to type any date because the time in the text box will be entered several times everyday.

Answer (score 0):

You can try follwoing query:-

```
SELECT * 
FROM YOUR_TABLE 
WHERE `time` >= ADDTIME(CURTIME(),-59);
```

Hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

As per the information you provided in your question

If your column type is `time` and default: 00:00:00

then you can try this query

```
 SELECT *
 FROM Table_Name 
 WHERE your_time_field = '05:00:00'
```

Comment: Its not just I want to get data only for 5 a.m, but for any time I enter. If I enter 6.15 a.m. or any other time, I should get the real time data stored in the database for that particular time.

Comment: so whats the problem, just change the time in where clause.. eg for 6:15 it should be  `'06:15:00' `

Answer (score 0):

SELECT *
     FROM Table_Name 
     WHERE your_time_field < value
     ORDER BY your_time_field DESC
     LIMIT 1;